# D-Bus >= 1.6 required

Tags: bluetooth, dbus

I am trying to make Bluez work for Kubuntu, and after reading some threads, it seems this
command is supposed to make it all work:
`sudo apt install libdbus-1-dev libudev-dev libical-dev libreadline-dev`
This is needed because of Bluez's `./configure` otherwise falls with the error `D-Bus >= 1.6 is required`.
However, when I issue the command above, I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libreadline-dev is already the newest version (7.0-5).
libreadline-dev set to manually installed.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libdb-dev libdb5.3-dev
Suggested packages:
  db5.3-doc
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libdb-dev libdb5.3-dev libdbus-1-dev libical-dev libudev-dev
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 39 not upgraded.
Need to get 1,288 kB/1,290 kB of archives.
After this operation, 7,273 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Ign:1 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libdbus-1-dev amd64 1.12.10-1ubuntu2.1
Ign:2 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libdb5.3-dev amd64 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.1ubuntu0.1
Err:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic/main amd64 libical-dev amd64 3.0.4-0ubuntu3
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:4 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libudev-dev amd64 239-7ubuntu10.14
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libdbus-1-dev amd64 1.12.10-1ubuntu2.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates/main amd64 libdb5.3-dev amd64 5.3.28+dfsg1-0.1ubuntu0.1
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/dbus/libdbus-1-dev_1.12.10-1ubuntu2.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/d/db5.3/libdb5.3-dev_5.3.28+dfsg1-0.1ubuntu0.1_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libi/libical3/libical-dev_3.0.4-0ubuntu3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/s/systemd/libudev-dev_239-7ubuntu10.14_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, try running apt-get update or apt-get --fix-missing.
```

The obvious question is, what needs to be done?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.10 ("Cosmic Cuttlefish") is EOL - you need to upgrade to a supported release. See [wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)

Comment: I did try, the update resource says "Surge protection".